# highcharts - create a total sumline of an existing serie

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a simple line graph with irregular x values.
What I need is a function to create a totalsum line like: 
for each x-value calculate:ysum=ysum + y

I could prepare this in the database but it would be nice to calculate it on clientside.
Could someone help me to start with this?
Unfortunately I am a total javascript newbie. Perhaps I can use the technical indicator plugin (https://github.com/laff/technical-indicators) and add a total-sum function?

Thanks in advance for any help

grassu

Comment: What's your data look like?  Just loop it, sum your y points and add it as another series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a function like this:

```
function getSumTotal(data) {
    var totalList = [], total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        total += data[i];
        totalList.push(total);
    }
    return totalList;
}
var tokyo = [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6];
var tokyoSumTotal = getSumTotal(tokyo);
```

Which you can put in highcharts like this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: tokyo
}, {
    name: 'Tokyo TotalSum',
    data: tokyoSumTotal
}]
```

Here's an example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs3RZ/1/)